# Why can't I compile an android studio project using lower API?

Tags: android, xml

I have made a simple app with Android Studio using API 25 (Nougat) but now I want to build an APK for API 21 (Lollipop) so I have changed "compile SDK version" in the Project Structure to API 21 but Android Studio has given me the following error:

```
D:\AndroidStudioProject\ArduinoData\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v23\values-v23.xml
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(34) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(34) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
D:\AndroidStudioProject\ArduinoData\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v24\values-v24.xml
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

I know that it is probably a graphic incompatibility but I don't know how to resolve it so have you any idea to fix it?

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <!-- Customize your theme here.
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>-->
    </style>

</resources>
```

**build.grandle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.acerbisgianluca.arduinodata"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Is your problem solved by my new answer?

Comment: my problem hasn't solved yet

Comment: Please update your code by the below answer.

Comment: Is the new answer worked? At my end, it's working fine now.

Comment: It gives me the following error and when I try to install it Android Studios says that it is not available for download **Error:Failed to find Build Tools revision 25.1.2
<a href="install.build.tools">Install Build Tools 21.1.2 and sync project</a>**

Comment: It will be 21.1.2,  not 25.1.2

Comment: now it says **Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (21.1.2) is too low for project ':app'. Minimum required is 25.0.0
<a href="install.build.tools">Install Build Tools 25.0.0, update version in build file and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile:D:/AndroidStudioProject/ArduinoData/app/build.gradle">Open File</a>**

Comment: Have you changed the minSdkVersion to 25?

Comment: yes, I have already changed it

Comment: If you change the versions then you have to change the library versions accordingly.

Comment: now: **Error:No resource identifier found for attribute 'fullBackupContent' in package 'android'
Error:No resource identifier found for attribute 'roundIcon' in package 'android'
Error:No resource identifier found for attribute 'fullBackupContent' in package 'android'
Error:No resource identifier found for attribute 'roundIcon' in package 'android'**

Answer (score 0):

I think you have written compileSdkVersion 21 and targetSdkVersion 25 in your app level build.gradle file. targetSdkVersion should not be higher than compileSdkVersion. You did it correctly but you didnot add the update the `buildToolsVersion` and `appcompatlibrary` version for API Level 21.

Change the `buildToolsVersion` to `21.1.2`

Change the `appcompat` library version to `21.0.2` in the app level build.gradle file. You have to update the library versions as per the API level 21.

I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: in styles.xml there is only this line **<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">**

Comment: You have only one styles.xml?

Comment: yes, in values folder there are colors.xml, strings.xml and styles.xml. My app has only 2 page, one for the login and one to see the data from a database

Comment: Do you have anything for API level 23 or 24 in the values folder?

Comment: That doesnot matter as you have the higher version. Please change the parent in the styles.xml to Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

Comment: I have just made this but it doesn't work unfortunately